# Rendering newlines in escaped html

Tags: html, newline, line-breaks

We have a display message that is auto-generated by default, but may be overridden by GET vars  from the url. Since we need to treat the message as user input, it must be escaped for display. However, we want to retain the ability to include newlines.

**Newlines as `<br>`**
This won't work because escaping HTML destroys the `<br>` tag.

**Newlines as `\n`**
I can't figure out how to get `\n` to render as newlines. I thought putting it in a  tag would render correctly, but no luck: http://jsfiddle.net/7L932/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're doing is more or less fine, except for you should put `\n` character (newline), not the escape sequence in your html (and what Prinzhorn says also makes perfect sense, so I'll go upvote him).

Comment: Michael- sorry i don't understand the first part of your answer- can you clarify?

Comment: @Yarin you literally wrote "\n" instead of hitting the return key ;-)

Comment: Well, linked in jsfiddle is the HTML containing backslash and `n`. What you want is the character that `\n` combination stands for. Like, if you use string `"a\nb"` in javascript, it will not contain backslash and letter n.

Comment: ah got you- but the newline char will be coming from a string generated in code. Is there another type of character sequence that actually represents "return key"? (Sorry so ignorant)

Comment: What code? you mention not a single language. In the most common ones if you put `\n` into string literal it will be interpreted as linefeed. To preserve actual character combinations you need to double the backslash.

Comment: we're working with python and but yes i get it now- the mistake was writing `\n` in HTML instead of our Python string literal- thank you, was stupid

Comment: You're welcome. It is stupid to know something and do contrary to your knowledge, if you don't know something, it's not stupid, it's time to learn ;-)

Comment: And just as a follow up, apparently the equivalent of using `\n` directly in HTML would be the HTML entity code `&#10;` [(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/7L932/3/) ... though not sure of the utility. [HTML ASCII Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_ascii.asp)

Answer (score 10):

Escape the HTML, and **then** replace `\n` with `<br>`.

In case you want to use \n, I fix your fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/hr3bg/

Comment: Good point- we were letting our templating framework do the escaping for us but we could just do it manually..

Answer (score 9):

Setting wrapper html css to `white-space: pre-line` did the trick for me. It enables \n character's new line feature

Answer (score 3):

Your theory's sound, but `\n` is a not an HTML-recognised way of inserting a new line. It either comes in explicitly (as I've inserted in a new `.linebreaks` element) as a literal return in the markup, or, if you're using some intermediary scripting language that *does* recognise `\n` (like JS), do that (as I've done to your first `.linebreaks` with the jQuery code I inserted.

See my tweak to your example: http://jsfiddle.net/barney/7L932/2/